# Mystery XML date="__________" numeric string?

Tags: xml, date, vbulletin, phrases

I have this XML file that's a plug in/product for a vBulletin forum. It's basically a plug in to put social media icons below the user picture linking to that person's social media profiles. There's a field in their profile that they put their information in. For example, they put in their youtube channel name,and the YouTube icon will appear under their avatar when they post; when it's clicked on it links to that YouTube Channel.

I need to add some additional parts to it, but there's this code that is really puzzling me, and I haven't been able to find an answer through research.

There's a 10 digit string of numbers identifying each social media field. But I have no idea where these numbers come from. I've tried to do without, but the code will not work without different numbers for each additional field I want to put in. The code is below, I went a head and just put in the whole block in case it helps with details.

Also, sadly the person who wrote this plugin no longer responds to support questions. I *have* tried, as have others who were posting questions to the developer in July of last year and still have not gotten a response.

Thank you for your time!

```
            <phrases>
    <phrasetype name="vBulletin Settings" fieldname="vbsettings">
        <phrase name="setting_bebo_desc" date="1310939317" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Bebo profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_bebo_title" date="1310939317" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Bebo]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_facebook_desc" date="1310939293" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Facebook profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_facebook_title" date="1310939293" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Facebook]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_flickr_desc" date="1310939380" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Flickr profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_flickr_title" date="1310939380" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Flickr]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_google_desc" date="1310939305" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Google+ profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_google_title" date="1310939305" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Google+]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_linkedin_desc" date="1310939 346" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Linkedin profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_linkedin_title" date="1310939346" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Linkedin]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_myspace_desc" date="1310939 335" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Myspace profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_myspace_title" date="1310939335" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Myspace]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_block_status_desc" date="1311002227" username="Admin" version="1.0.1"><![CDATA[Select YES to enable icons within a block or NO to have the icons without a block.]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_block_status_title" date="1311002227" username="Admin" version="1.0.1"><![CDATA[Enable Block in Postbit]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_postbit_status_desc" date="1311157772" username="Admin" version="1.0.2"><![CDATA[Select YES to enable in postbit or NO to disable.]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_postbit_status_title" date="1311157772" username="Admin" version="1.0.2"><![CDATA[Enable Postbit]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_profile_location_desc" date="1311022873" username="Admin" version="1.0.1"><![CDATA[Enter the position you wish the block to appear in the members profile. Options = TOP, MIDDLE, BOTTOM (enter without commas)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_profile_location_title" date="1311022873" username="Admin" version="1.0.1"><![CDATA[Location in User Profile]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_profile_status_desc" date="1311002211" username="Admin" version="1.0.1"><![CDATA[Select YES to enable block in userprofiles or NO to disable.]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_profile_status_title" date="1311002211" username="Admin" version="1.0.1"><![CDATA[Enable in Profile]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_status_desc" date="1311157710" username="Admin" version="1.0.2"><![CDATA[Select YES to enable the mod or NO to disable.]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_social_status_title" date="1311157710" username="Admin" version="1.0.2"><![CDATA[Enable Social Networking in Profile and Postbit]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_tumblr_desc" date="1310939361" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Tumblr profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_tumblr_title" date="1310939361" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Tumblr]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_twitter_desc" date="1310939265" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Twitter profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_twitter_title" date="1310939265" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Twitter]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_vimeo_desc" date="1310939400" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Vimeo profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_vimeo_title" date="1310939400" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Vimeo]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_youtube_desc" date="1310939391" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Enter your Youtube profile field number. (Leave blank to disable)]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="setting_youtube_title" date="1310939391" username="Admin" version="1.0.1 Beta"><![CDATA[Youtube]]></phrase>
        <phrase name="settinggroup_socialpostbit" date="1310916979" username="Admin" version="1.0.1"><![CDATA[[Boydy]Social Networking in Postbit]]></phrase>
    </phrasetype>
</phrases>
```

Comment: Looks like the time difference between the current date. For example if you put this in Chrome debugger: `new Date(new Date() - 1310939317)` it gives a date around the 1st Jan 2014.

Comment: I strongly suggest going back to whoever gave you this XML document, and/or whoever wrote the code that generates it, and asking _THEM_ what this value is intended to be. We can guess, but only they will know for certain. And it may simply be an error in their code.

Comment: Those appear to be "Unix epoch" dates.  See http://www.epochconverter.com/, eg.

Comment: (The first date at the top is Sun, 17 Jul 2011 21:48:37 GMT.  The very last one is Sun, 17 Jul 2011 15:36:19 GMT.  The date for setting_social_postbit_status_title is Wed, 20 Jul 2011 10:29:32 GMT.)

Comment: (This number is milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.)

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you have are "Unix epoch" dates -- milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.

See, for example, http://www.epochconverter.com/.